# sql server 2008 - Add a line that counts different values

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, sum

Using SQL Server 2008 I get the following output:

[image: Output]

I would like to know if there is a way to sum up, in new lines, all the different texts of Col3 to show something like this:

[image: Desired ouptut]

Comment: Maybe using `GROUPING SETS`? Post the query you are using so we can help.

Comment: This is not normally a thing you do in SQL, it is most commonly done at UI level via SSRS, xls, etc. If you still need to do it in sql then, as @kirchner said, grouping sets is an option; or a quick and dirty one is just manipulating a union (with an aggregation query) to keep the columns in corresponding numbers and data type

Comment: @Junajo, can you share your query? Also, how and where do you want to show your extra column. Your result returns 3 columns while you are adding only one. Are you going to sent result of the query to some report?

Comment: The query is a little bit dirty: it joins tables not created by me in a difficult way. I will try to simulate it in a non-production environement, with invented values and see if I can come back to this. Thanks anyway for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a quick and dirty method, like jayvee suggested. It will only work if the first column of your query is a type you can put a string into. If it not, you may be able to move the summary output to another column.

```
DECLARE @TestData as TABLE (Col1 nvarchar(50), Col2 nvarchar(50), Col3 nvarchar(50));

Insert Into @TestData
Select 'Whatever1', 'Day1', 'Text1'
UNION ALL Select 'Whatever1', 'Day2', 'Text1'
UNION ALL Select 'Whatever1', 'Day3', 'Text2'
UNION ALL Select 'Whatever2', 'Day1', 'Text1'
UNION ALL Select 'Whatever2', 'Day2', 'Text3'
UNION ALL Select 'Whatever3', 'Day1', 'Text3'
UNION ALL Select 'Whatever3', 'Day2', 'Text2'
UNION ALL Select 'Whatever3', 'Day3', 'Text3';

With OriginalQuery as (
    --This should be your original query
    Select Col1, Col2, Col3 from @TestData
), GroupData as(
    -- This is the summary data you want
    Select Col3, COUNT(Col3) as ColCount from OriginalQuery Group By Col3
)
Select * from OriginalQuery  --Output the original data
UNION ALL
--This is formatting the group data, 
--and adding null columns so it matches the original query length, or the union will fail
Select 'Number of ' + Col3 + ' = ' + Cast(ColCount as nvarchar(10)),
    NULL, NULL  --One for each column in original query except the first one
From GroupData;
```